# Calculation of hash of a string (MD5, SHA) as a basis for CPU benchmarking

Tags: hash, md5, cpu, benchmarking, sha

I know that there are many applications and tools available for benching the computational power of CPUs especially in terms of **floating point and integer calculations**.

What I want to know is that how good is to use the hashing functions such as MD5, SHA, ... for benchmarking CPUs? Does these functions include enough floating point and integer calculations that applying a series of those hashing functions could be a good basis for cpu becnhmarking?

In case platform matters, I'm concerned with Windows and .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 and SHA hash  functions do not use floating point at all. They are completely implemented using discrete math

Comment: What about other hashing functions? Are all implemented using discrete math?

Comment: All standard hashing functions do not use fp AFAIK, however I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've never heard of a hash function that did anything with FP.  Since some FP bit patterns represent NaN, leading to NaN results when adding/subtracting/multiplying any other value, it seems unlikely to lead to a good hash.  Also, FP binary representations aren't as portable as binary integers, and not all hardware even has FP hardware, so there are many reasons to avoid FP, and none in favour of it, for hash functions.